# Creating custom labels on xaxis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to following code: it plots 3 * 2 subplots, each of them have "days" on xaxis, and number of people on yaxis. I'm trying converts days into years on plot, but all I tried doesn't work. I would like labels on axis to be np.arange(0, 15, 1) (in years), not np.arange(1, 365 * 15, 364) (in days). Should be simple, but I don't get it.
Can somebody help me, please?

```

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(25, 17))


titles = ['S', 'L', 'D', 'B', 'D_0', 'B_0']

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    if i == 0:
        y = countS
    elif i == 1:
        y = countL
    elif i == 2:
        y = countD
    elif i == 3:
        y = countB
    elif i == 4:
        y = countD_0
    elif i == 5:
        y = countB_0

    ax.plot(days, y, color='m')

    ax.set_title(titles[i])
    ax.set_xlabel('Дни')
    ax.set_ylabel('Количество')
    ax.set_facecolor('#f4f4f4')
    ax.grid(color='white')

    ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(1, 365 * 15, 364))


    ax.tick_params('x', labelrotation=45)

fig.suptitle('Динамика заболеваемости', fontsize=20)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, hspace=0.4)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I tried just to make

```
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 15, 1))
```

but it obviously doesn't work as I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use [*broadcasting*](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to divide the array of `days` by `365` :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

days = np.arange(1, 365*15, 364)
counts = [np.random.randint(100, size=len(days)) for _ in range(6)]

x = days / 365

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(25, 17))

titles = ['S', 'L', 'D', 'B', 'D_0', 'B_0']
for ax, count, title in zip(axes.flat, counts, titles):
    ax.plot(x, count, color='m')
    ax.set_xlabel('Дни')
    ax.set_ylabel('Количество')
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_facecolor('#f4f4f4')
    ax.grid(color='white')
    ax.tick_params('x', labelrotation=45)

fig.suptitle('Динамика заболеваемости', fontsize=20)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, hspace=0.4)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show();
```

Output (*the first 2 rows*) :

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Simple question, is it possible to plot years in step=1, not 2? Or because arrays I plot are counted in step=2 in days I canno't do it?

Comment: nvm, solved with  ax.xaxis.set_ticks. Thank you!

Comment: Yes you can add `ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 16, 1))`. You're welcome ;)